# Fat jar maven requirement

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am not good with maven.

And based on maven plugins, my below pom would build 3 things on maven install:

1) executable jar as smartApp.jar

2) conf/application.properties

3) smartApp.lib  with all dependencies

4) tk_installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar

I created a fat jar as tk_installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar but this would still need smartApp.lib and conf folder in parallel for execution.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tk.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>tk_installer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>tk-generator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--scope>provided</scope -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>smartApp</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                <configuration>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>


                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>${project.build.finalName}.lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.tk.platform.yamlgenerator.YamlGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>

                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>

                <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
       </excludes>  

        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>${project.build.finalName}.lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.tk.platform.yamlgenerator.YamlGeneratorApplication</mainClass>
          </manifest>
           <manifestEntries>
              <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
           </manifestEntries>

        </archive>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <configuration> 
                <webResources> <resource> <directory>src/webapp</directory> </resource> </webResources> 
                </configuration> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Why? Spring Boot already creates the needed executable jar... Why are you working your way around that? You are fighting the framework instead of using it.

Comment: requirement over requirement moved a bit far and forgot the basics, sir. Thanks a ton. cheers

Answer (score 0):

For anyone messing up use spring-boot jar building support and just provide below plugin instead of whole thing above for creating a fat jar as below:

```
<build>
            <finalName>smartApp</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Referred below link:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

thanks [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)